# vc++ Line Graph Example

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

Can someone please provide me with a hint on how to draw a line graph in vc++ 6.0?

Comment: Please take the time to write your english proplery next time. Remember that people need to understand your question in order to answer it. So stop abbreviate.

Answer (score 2):

In MFC:

See [LineTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzc1344s(VS.80).aspx) and also MoveTo from CDC.

And use CPaintDC to draw on the OnPaint event like [here](http://www.gidforums.com/t-5963.html).